# Drupal 7: Displaying data from a web service

Tags: web-services, drupal-7

I'm using Drupal 7, and I need to retrieve data from a web service. This data cannot be stored in the Drupal database due to regulations. What would be the best practice for retrieving this data: using Java, Drupal Entities, or storing in tokens?

We are currently making calls based on an ID stored in the database and displaying the data from the web service associated with that ID.

The problem with this is that it's all being done outside of Drupal, and we are unable to use Drupal to manage any of this content. So we have many modules with custom code to do everything from creating forms, pre-filling forms, tying into a users account on Drupal, etc.

We are at a point where we can totally refactor how this works.

Do you have any suggestion on how we can improve this?

Note: The amount of data we need to store will be large. I was thinking that maybe we could create an entity around the web service data and then show the data related to a field by adding tokens as the default value. The ID stored in the database would change what is shown through the tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Well i suppose you could start of course with a custom module , create a hook_menu() and a url to "parse" the info you are getting through the service.Create the extra tables that will store your data - maybe serialized if its too big.Use the Schema module to correctly create
the mymodule.install file inside your module.

Is it an XML service? Go with [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) , on the callback of this menu() use db_query to store your data in your table.

From there i suppose you can play around with all the nice [drupal hooks](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal) to display and manipulate your data

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, your refactoring should not be to store data in drupal. 
I needed to make a location service site a few months ago and needed to use Google Maps API to fill missing geolocation data.

How about a structure like this:
You make the form and data(users, node types, etc) using normal drupal nodes and users. Then, using hook_node_insert, hook_node_update and hook_node_load, you can force drupal to submit or retrieve the information to the other service. hook_node_presave would be useful to clear out user input before saving it to drupal database(note that insert hook will be called after presave. ).

You can still use drupal to create forms, store necessary data, etc.

Also note that Views module will not work with this. Check Views Data Source module.